# How do I write a -replace in powershell where a number follows a sequence

Tags: regex, powershell

For example, let's say I want to take the string `Hello World` and use a `-replace` to output "World1". This was my attempt at the expression:

```
"Hello World" -replace '.*(World)','$11'
```

But the problem here is that it's seeing $11 as the 11th sequence, not $1 followed by 1. I've tried searching for an escape character to specify that I want a 1 following the $1, but haven't found anything.

The real world problem I was trying to solve is to take a bunch of email addresses and create aliases with a number on the end. For example

```
jsmith@example.com
```

becomes

```
jsmith1@example.com
jsmith2@example.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `"Hello World" -replace '.*(World)','${1}1'`

It seemed to work here

```
        var s1 = "Hello World";
        var r = ".*(World)";
        var p = "${1}1";
        var outstr = Regex.Replace(s1, r, p);
        Console.WriteLine(outstr);
```

Output `World1`

Comment: Beautiful, does the job. Thanks!
Happen to know why this works and what the {} means in this context? I'm struggling to find documentation for it.

Comment: Nevermind; just found it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$Email = "jsmith@example.com"
$Domain = ($Email -split "@")[-1]
for ($i=1;$i -le 5;$i++)
{
(($Email -split "@")[0] + $i),$Domain -join "@"
}

## Result 
jsmith1@example.com
jsmith2@example.com
jsmith3@example.com
jsmith4@example.com
jsmith5@example.com
```

If you don't need it you can avoid the for loop and just replace the $i in this section:

```
$Email -split "@")[0] + $i
```

Comment: I ended up using a couple of -replace statements to achieve it, but I did think of using joins.